# Getting the values of one-to-many relationships in the parent entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

So I have a Doctrine 2 ORM entity, Trust, with several one-to-many relationships. I can't work out how to populate the arrays for these.

```
class Trust implements \JsonSerializable {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TrustPurpose", mappedBy="trust")
     */
    private $purpose;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            [...]
            'purpose' => $this->purpose,
            [...]
        ];
    }

}
```

In my controller, I might use something like the following.

```
return new JsonResponse($this->entityManager->find(Trust::class, 1));
```

And get the following output

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Some Trust",
    "purpose" : {

    }
}
```

I'm struggling to find documentation on how to edit entity Trust to automatically populate my purpose records?

TrustPurpose

```
class TrustPurpose implements \JsonSerializable {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $purpose;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Trust", inversedBy="purpose")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="trust_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $trust;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'purpose' => $this->purpose,
            'trust' => $this->trust,
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, this was just lazy. I will edit my question with code.

Comment: @Veve See edited post - thank you.

Comment: Thanks :) Can you also show us the content of the TrustPurpose entity?

Comment: @Veve Yes, done.

Comment: In your Trust::jsonSerilaze method, $purpose = $this->getPurpose();  That will kickoff the lazy loading of the purpose entity.  Lazy loading is an interesting topic.  Of course you also have TrustPurpose trying to serialize Trust so you will probably end up with an infinite loop.  I would strongly suggest taking the time to work through the example in the manual http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: @Cerad Using getPurpose() didn't make any difference... Interestingly, however, with the code exactly as above, for TrustPurpose, just using $this->trust, I notice that I in fact do get the one Trust record inserted into the JSON output. Why should it work the one (unintended, as it happens) way and not the other?

Comment: Gonna send you back to the manual I'm afraid.  But I will give you a hint.  Presumably, a trust can have multiple purposes.  Does that not sort of suggest the need for an array?  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, I saw that earlier today and added the line (use ArrayCollection, set then in construct set $this->purpose = new ArrayCollection() ...

Comment: @Cerad $purpose is an ArrayCollection - an object - rather than an array...? Can I feed that as a value to JsonSerialise? I'm starting to think that the answer is no?

Comment: @Cerad Got it! My getPurpose() function shouldn't be return $this->purpose; but rather return $this->purpose->toArray();. Now working and I can go to sleep! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Cerad Interestingly, I've been able to add most of the code that I added in trying to solve the problem... Setting the ArrayCollection in construct, the getPurpose function ... The only difference between the code above no and the working code is that 'purpose' => $this->purpose is now 'purpose' => $this->purpose->toArray() ... Interesting.